# switcher php. my question is with switcher. when I switch and form should be changed dynamically

Tags: php, html

[image: I marked]

I have 3 options. They are chair , war and peace, acme disc. switcher php. my question is with switcher. when I switch and form should be changed dynamically. I am beginner on php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Product add</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="PrAd">
            <h2>
                <b>Product Add</b>
                <button class="button">Save</button>
            </h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form>
                <label for="SKU">SKU</label>
                <input type="text" id="formbox" name="SKU"><br>
                <label for="Name ">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="formbox" name="Name"><br>
                <label for="Price">Price</label>
                <input type="number" id="formbox" name="Price"><br>
                <label>Type Switcher</label>
                <select id="type" name="product">
                    <option value="Acme Disc">Acme Disc</option>
                    <option value="War and Peace">War and Peace</option>
                    <option value="Chair">Chair</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php  

        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "_when I switch and form should be changed dynamically"_ - Switch to what? What type of dynamic change?  This question is unclear. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you're trying to do - It looks more like a javascript question rather than PHP

Comment: sorry it was my first question. do u see photo?

Comment: @Jastin this is related to client side i-e javascript so for this you will have to create block of fields and initially make them hidden and by attaching `onChange` event to your dropdown field you can call some javascript function that will check the selected value and based on that it makes relevent fields visible. eg: `onChange="prodType(this.value);"` where `prodType` is javascript function where you will check the value and based on it shows relevant fields.Hope you get the idea.

Comment: @Adeel Tahir, Thank you bro. How can I send you this file?

Comment: @Jastin i have added snippet for you.Hope this solves what you are looking.You can add your fields in desired blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function prodType(prod){
  var acmeAttributes = document.getElementById("acme_disc_attributes");
  var warPeaceAttributes = document.getElementById("war_peace_attributes");
  var chairAttributes = document.getElementById("chair_attributes");
  
  acmeAttributes.style.display="none";
  warPeaceAttributes.style.display="none";
  chairAttributes.style.display="none";
  
  if(prod=="Acme Disc"){
    acmeAttributes.style.display="block";
  }else if(prod=="War and Peace"){
    warPeaceAttributes.style.display="block";
  }else if(prod=="Chair"){
  chairAttributes.style.display="block";
  }
}
```

```css
.fieldbox{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Product add</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="PrAd">
            <h2>
                <b>Product Add</b>
                <button class="button">Save</button>
            </h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <form>
                <label for="SKU">SKU</label>
                <input type="text" id="formbox" name="SKU"><br>
                <label for="Name ">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="formbox" name="Name"><br>
                <label for="Price">Price</label>
                <input type="number" id="formbox" name="Price"><br>
                <label>Type Switcher</label>
                <select id="type" name="product" onChange="prodType(this.value);">
                    <option value="">Choose Switcher</option>
                    <option value="Acme Disc">Acme Disc</option>
                    <option value="War and Peace">War and Peace</option>
                    <option value="Chair">Chair</option>
                </select>
                
                <div class="fieldbox" id="acme_disc_attributes">
                  <label>Size</label>
                  <input type="text" name="size" value="">
                </div>
                
                <div class="fieldbox" id="war_peace_attributes">
                  <label>Weight</label>
                  <input type="text" name="weight" value="">
                </div>
                
                <div class="fieldbox" id="chair_attributes">
                  <label>Length</label>
                  <input type="text" name="length"><br>
                 <label>Width</label>
                <input type="text" name="width"><br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Bro OOH thank you.  I have little question. where should I add code which start with 'function'?

Comment: @Jastin the function is javascript function you can add that before body close tag `</body>` as `<script> FUNCTION HERE</script>` or even you can place before head closing tag `</head>`

Comment: Thanks bro. Bro can you write me by mail?

Comment: @Jastin what you want me to write in email, share your email and explain.

Comment: I want to send you description the task. sobirovmustafo83@gmail.com I will wait bro your email.